# How to align many parameters in a single card

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

**My Requiremnet** Align 8 cards in a single row. Each card to include 4 types of data say Average,Range,Min & Max.

**What I have tried**
The code I've tried for this is

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col">
    <div class=" card card-stats">
      <div class=" card-body">
        <div class=" row">
          <div class=" col-5">
            <div class=" info-icon text-center icon-primary">
              <i class=" icons icon-shape-star"> </i>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class=" col-7">
            <div class=" numbers">
              <p class=" card-category">Followers</p>
              <h6 class=" card-title">+45k</h6>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class=" row">
          <div class=" col-5">
            <!-- <div class=" numbers"> -->
              <p class=" card-category">Average</p>
              <h6 class=" card-title">+45k</h6>
            <!-- </div> -->
          </div>
          <div class=" col-7">
            <div class=" numbers">
              <p class=" card-category">Followers</p>
              <h6 class=" card-title">+45k</h6>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class=" card-footer">
        <hr />

        <div class=" stats">
          <i class=" icons icon-sound-wave"> </i> Last Research
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="col">
    <div class=" card card-stats">
      <div class=" card-body">
        <div class=" row">
          <div class=" col-5">
            <div class=" info-icon text-center icon-primary">
              <i class=" icons icon-shape-star"> </i>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class=" col-7">
            <div class=" numbers">
              <p class=" card-category">Followers</p>
              <h6 class=" card-title">+45k</h6>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class=" row">
          <div class=" col-5">
            <!-- <div class=" numbers"> -->
              <p class=" card-category">Average</p>
              <h6 class=" card-title">+45k</h6>
            <!-- </div> -->
          </div>
          <div class=" col-7">
            <div class=" numbers">
              <p class=" card-category">Followers</p>
              <h6 class=" card-title">+45k</h6>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class=" card-footer">
        <hr />

        <div class=" stats">
          <i class=" icons icon-sound-wave"> </i> Last Research
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="col">
    <div class=" card card-stats">
      <div class=" card-body">
        <div class=" row">
          <div class=" col-5">
            <div class=" info-icon text-center icon-primary">
              <i class=" icons icon-shape-star"> </i>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class=" col-7">
            <div class=" numbers">
              <p class=" card-category">Followers</p>
              <h6 class=" card-title">+45k</h6>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class=" row">
          <div class=" col-5">
            <!-- <div class=" numbers"> -->
              <p class=" card-category">Average</p>
              <h6 class=" card-title">+45k</h6>
            <!-- </div> -->
          </div>
          <div class=" col-7">
            <div class=" numbers">
              <p class=" card-category">Followers</p>
              <h6 class=" card-title">+45k</h6>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class=" card-footer">
        <hr />

        <div class=" stats">
          <i class=" icons icon-sound-wave"> </i> Last Research
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="col">
    <div class=" card card-stats">
      <div class=" card-body">
        <div class=" row">
          <div class=" col-5">
            <div class=" info-icon text-center icon-primary">
              <i class=" icons icon-shape-star"> </i>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class=" col-7">
            <div class=" numbers">
              <p class=" card-category">Followers</p>
              <h6 class=" card-title">+45k</h6>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class=" row">
          <div class=" col-5">
            <!-- <div class=" numbers"> -->
              <p class=" card-category">Average</p>
              <h6 class=" card-title">+45k</h6>
            <!-- </div> -->
          </div>
          <div class=" col-7">
            <div class=" numbers">
              <p class=" card-category">Followers</p>
              <h6 class=" card-title">+45k</h6>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class=" card-footer">
        <hr />

        <div class=" stats">
          <i class=" icons icon-sound-wave"> </i> Last Research
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>


  <div class="col">
    <div class=" card card-stats">
      <div class=" card-body">
        <div class=" row">
          <div class=" col-5">
            <div class=" info-icon text-center icon-primary">
              <i class=" icons icon-shape-star"> </i>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class=" col-7">
            <div class=" numbers">
              <p class=" card-category">Followers</p>
              <h6 class=" card-title">+45k</h6>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class=" row">
          <div class=" col-5">
            <!-- <div class=" numbers"> -->
              <p class=" card-category">Average</p>
              <h6 class=" card-title">+45k</h6>
            <!-- </div> -->
          </div>
          <div class=" col-7">
            <div class=" numbers">
              <p class=" card-category">Followers</p>
              <h6 class=" card-title">+45k</h6>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class=" card-footer">
        <hr />

        <div class=" stats">
          <i class=" icons icon-sound-wave"> </i> Last Research
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="col">
    <div class=" card card-stats">
      <div class=" card-body">
        <div class=" row">
          <div class=" col-5">
            <div class=" info-icon text-center icon-primary">
              <i class=" icons icon-shape-star"> </i>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class=" col-7">
            <div class=" numbers">
              <p class=" card-category">Followers</p>
              <h6 class=" card-title">+45k</h6>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class=" row">
          <div class=" col-5">
            <!-- <div class=" numbers"> -->
              <p class=" card-category">Average</p>
              <h6 class=" card-title">+45k</h6>
            <!-- </div> -->
          </div>
          <div class=" col-7">
            <div class=" numbers">
              <p class=" card-category">Followers</p>
              <h6 class=" card-title">+45k</h6>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class=" card-footer">
        <hr />

        <div class=" stats">
          <i class=" icons icon-sound-wave"> </i> Last Research
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="col">
    <div class=" card card-stats">
      <div class=" card-body">
        <div class=" row">
          <div class=" col-5">
            <div class=" info-icon text-center icon-primary">
              <i class=" icons icon-shape-star"> </i>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class=" col-7">
            <div class=" numbers">
              <p class=" card-category">Followers</p>
              <h6 class=" card-title">+45k</h6>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class=" row">
          <div class=" col-5">
            <!-- <div class=" numbers"> -->
              <p class=" card-category">Average</p>
              <h6 class=" card-title">+45k</h6>
            <!-- </div> -->
          </div>
          <div class=" col-7">
            <div class=" numbers">
              <p class=" card-category">Followers</p>
              <h6 class=" card-title">+45k</h6>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class=" card-footer">
        <hr />

        <div class=" stats">
          <i class=" icons icon-sound-wave"> </i> Last Research
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="col">
    <div class=" card card-stats">
      <div class=" card-body">
        <div class=" row">
          <div class=" col-5">
            <div class=" info-icon text-center icon-primary">
              <i class=" icons icon-shape-star"> </i>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class=" col-7">
            <div class=" numbers">
              <p class=" card-category">Followers</p>
              <h6 class=" card-title">+45k</h6>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class=" row">
          <div class=" col-5">
            <!-- <div class=" numbers"> -->
              <p class=" card-category">Average</p>
              <h6 class=" card-title">+45k</h6>
            <!-- </div> -->
          </div>
          <div class=" col-7">
            <div class=" numbers">
              <p class=" card-category">Followers</p>
              <h6 class=" card-title">+45k</h6>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class=" card-footer">
        <hr />

        <div class=" stats">
          <i class=" icons icon-sound-wave"> </i> Last Research
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

But it gives some distorted display as shown in the below image. I am not able to remove the extra padding\space between\within each card. If I remove the padding some of the items - icons, text... - go out of the card.

Please help me to make the cards aligned properly in the same row.
[image: card_display]

My expected output of the card is as shown in the below image

[image]

**Updated code using answer from Nisharg Shah**

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col px-1">
    <div class=" card card-stats">
      <div class=" card-body">
        <div class=" row">
          <div class=" col-5">
            <div class=" info-icon text-center icon-primary">
              <i class=" fas fa-clock"> </i>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class=" col-7">
            <div class=" numbers">
              <p class=" card-category">Average</p>
              <h6 class=" card-title">43.11</h6>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class=" row">
          <div class=" col-6">
            <!-- <div class=" numbers"> -->
            <p style="font-size: 10px;" class=" card-category">Range</p>
            <h6 class=" card-title">26.87</h6>
            <!-- </div> -->
          </div>
          <div class=" col-6">
            <div class=" numbers">
              <p style="font-size: 10px;" class=" card-category">Min</p>
              <h6 class=" card-title">98.44</h6>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class=" card-footer">
        <hr />

        <div class=" stats">
          <i class=" fa fa-car"> </i> Max
          <span class="numbers">87.22</span>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="col px-1">
    <div class=" card card-stats">
      <div class=" card-body">
        <div class=" row">
          <div class=" col-5">
            <div class=" info-icon text-center icon-primary">
              <i class=" fas fa-clock"> </i>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class=" col-7">
            <div class=" numbers">
              <p class=" card-category">Average</p>
              <h6 class=" card-title">43.11</h6>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class=" row">
          <div class=" col-6">
            <!-- <div class=" numbers"> -->
            <p style="font-size: 10px;" class=" card-category">Range</p>
            <h6 class=" card-title">26.87</h6>
            <!-- </div> -->
          </div>
          <div class=" col-6">
            <div class=" numbers">
              <p style="font-size: 10px;" class=" card-category">Min</p>
              <h6 class=" card-title">98.44</h6>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class=" card-footer">
        <hr />

        <div class=" stats">
          <i class=" fa fa-car"> </i> Max
          <span class="numbers">87.22</span>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="col px-1">
    <div class=" card card-stats">
      <div class=" card-body">
        <div class=" row">
          <div class=" col-5">
            <div class=" info-icon text-center icon-primary">
              <i class=" fas fa-clock"> </i>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class=" col-7">
            <div class=" numbers">
              <p class=" card-category">Average</p>
              <h6 class=" card-title">43.11</h6>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class=" row">
          <div class=" col-6">
            <!-- <div class=" numbers"> -->
            <p style="font-size: 10px;" class=" card-category">Range</p>
            <h6 class=" card-title">26.87</h6>
            <!-- </div> -->
          </div>
          <div class=" col-6">
            <div class=" numbers">
              <p style="font-size: 10px;" class=" card-category">Min</p>
              <h6 class=" card-title">98.44</h6>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class=" card-footer">
        <hr />

        <div class=" stats">
          <i class=" fa fa-car"> </i> Max
          <span class="numbers">87.22</span>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="col px-1">
    <div class=" card card-stats">
      <div class=" card-body">
        <div class=" row">
          <div class=" col-5">
            <div class=" info-icon text-center icon-primary">
              <i class=" fas fa-clock"> </i>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class=" col-7">
            <div class=" numbers">
              <p class=" card-category">Average</p>
              <h6 class=" card-title">43.11</h6>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class=" row">
          <div class=" col-6">
            <!-- <div class=" numbers"> -->
            <p style="font-size: 10px;" class=" card-category">Range</p>
            <h6 class=" card-title">26.87</h6>
            <!-- </div> -->
          </div>
          <div class=" col-6">
            <div class=" numbers">
              <p style="font-size: 10px;" class=" card-category">Min</p>
              <h6 class=" card-title">98.44</h6>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class=" card-footer">
        <hr />

        <div class=" stats">
          <i class=" fa fa-car"> </i> Max
          <span class="numbers">87.22</span>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="col px-1">
    <div class=" card card-stats">
      <div class=" card-body">
        <div class=" row">
          <div class=" col-5">
            <div class=" info-icon text-center icon-primary">
              <i class=" fas fa-clock"> </i>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class=" col-7">
            <div class=" numbers">
              <p class=" card-category">Average</p>
              <h6 class=" card-title">43.11</h6>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class=" row">
          <div class=" col-6">
            <!-- <div class=" numbers"> -->
            <p style="font-size: 10px;" class=" card-category">Range</p>
            <h6 class=" card-title">26.87</h6>
            <!-- </div> -->
          </div>
          <div class=" col-6">
            <div class=" numbers">
              <p style="font-size: 10px;" class=" card-category">Min</p>
              <h6 class=" card-title">98.44</h6>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class=" card-footer">
        <hr />

        <div class=" stats">
          <i class=" fa fa-car"> </i> Max
          <span class="numbers">87.22</span>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="col px-1">
    <div class=" card card-stats">
      <div class=" card-body">
        <div class=" row">
          <div class=" col-5">
            <div class=" info-icon text-center icon-primary">
              <i class=" fas fa-clock"> </i>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class=" col-7">
            <div class=" numbers">
              <p class=" card-category">Average</p>
              <h6 class=" card-title">43.11</h6>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class=" row">
          <div class=" col-6">
            <!-- <div class=" numbers"> -->
            <p style="font-size: 10px;" class=" card-category">Range</p>
            <h6 class=" card-title">26.87</h6>
            <!-- </div> -->
          </div>
          <div class=" col-6">
            <div class=" numbers">
              <p style="font-size: 10px;" class=" card-category">Min</p>
              <h6 class=" card-title">98.44</h6>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class=" card-footer">
        <hr />

        <div class=" stats">
          <i class=" fa fa-car"> </i> Max
          <span class="numbers">87.22</span>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="col px-1">
    <div class=" card card-stats">
      <div class=" card-body">
        <div class=" row">
          <div class=" col-5">
            <div class=" info-icon text-center icon-primary">
              <i class=" fas fa-clock"> </i>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class=" col-7">
            <div class=" numbers">
              <p class=" card-category">Average</p>
              <h6 class=" card-title">43.11</h6>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class=" row">
          <div class=" col-6">
            <!-- <div class=" numbers"> -->
            <p style="font-size: 10px;" class=" card-category">Range</p>
            <h6 class=" card-title">26.87</h6>
            <!-- </div> -->
          </div>
          <div class=" col-6">
            <div class=" numbers">
              <p style="font-size: 10px;" class=" card-category">Min</p>
              <h6 class=" card-title">98.44</h6>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class=" card-footer">
        <hr />

        <div class=" stats">
          <i class=" fa fa-car"> </i> Max
          <span class="numbers">87.22</span>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="col px-1">
    <div class=" card card-stats">
      <div class=" card-body">
        <div class=" row">
          <div class=" col-5">
            <div class=" info-icon text-center icon-primary">
              <i class=" fas fa-clock"> </i>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class=" col-7">
            <div class=" numbers">
              <p class=" card-category">Average</p>
              <h6 class=" card-title">43.11</h6>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class=" row">
          <div class=" col-6">
            <!-- <div class=" numbers"> -->
            <p style="font-size: 10px;" class=" card-category">Range</p>
            <h6 class=" card-title">26.87</h6>
            <!-- </div> -->
          </div>
          <div class=" col-6">
            <div class=" numbers">
              <p style="font-size: 10px;" class=" card-category">Min</p>
              <h6 class=" card-title">98.44</h6>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class=" card-footer">
        <hr />

        <div class=" stats">
          <i class=" fa fa-car"> </i> Max
          <span class="numbers">87.22</span>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

This displays as shown in the below image
[image]

I want to make the top icon smaller and to remove the extra space between above footer marked in green arrows in the image. Please help

Comment: You're missing css code, would you mind sharing it?

Comment: this is bootstrap

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">

Comment: Thank you , but that didn't give me what you showcased above! see the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Manju06/ugb8ywhv/19/

Comment: @jAntoni Hi, you come again with different approach.

Comment: Hi @NishargShah, I am using the same solution(code) you gave me yesterday to include 4 parameter data in the same card. In your code I have changed to  add the same row again but replacing the icon with value.  Please help me with it. I have given the image which says the format I need to display my data inside the card.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add `px-1` class in all `col` classes, so it reduces the gap between cards.

`px-1` = `.5rem` = `8px`, If you want to reduce more gap, you can add custom CSS on all `col` classes.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<div class="row">
  <div class="col px-1">
    <div class=" card card-stats">
      <div class=" card-body">
        <div class=" row">
          <div class=" col-5">
            <div class=" info-icon text-center icon-primary">
              <i class=" icons icon-shape-star"> </i>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class=" col-7">
            <div class=" numbers">
              <p class=" card-category">Followers</p>
              <h6 class=" card-title">+45k</h6>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class=" row">
          <div class=" col-5">
            <!-- <div class=" numbers"> -->
              <p class=" card-category">Average</p>
              <h6 class=" card-title">+45k</h6>
            <!-- </div> -->
          </div>
          <div class=" col-7">
            <div class=" numbers">
              <p class=" card-category">Followers</p>
              <h6 class=" card-title">+45k</h6>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class=" card-footer">
        <hr />

        <div class=" stats">
          <i class=" icons icon-sound-wave"> </i> Last Research
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="col px-1">
    <div class=" card card-stats">
      <div class=" card-body">
        <div class=" row">
          <div class=" col-5">
            <div class=" info-icon text-center icon-primary">
              <i class=" icons icon-shape-star"> </i>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class=" col-7">
            <div class=" numbers">
              <p class=" card-category">Followers</p>
              <h6 class=" card-title">+45k</h6>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class=" row">
          <div class=" col-5">
            <!-- <div class=" numbers"> -->
              <p class=" card-category">Average</p>
              <h6 class=" card-title">+45k</h6>
            <!-- </div> -->
          </div>
          <div class=" col-7">
            <div class=" numbers">
              <p class=" card-category">Followers</p>
              <h6 class=" card-title">+45k</h6>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class=" card-footer">
        <hr />

        <div class=" stats">
          <i class=" icons icon-sound-wave"> </i> Last Research
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="col px-1">
    <div class=" card card-stats">
      <div class=" card-body">
        <div class=" row">
          <div class=" col-5">
            <div class=" info-icon text-center icon-primary">
              <i class=" icons icon-shape-star"> </i>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class=" col-7">
            <div class=" numbers">
              <p class=" card-category">Followers</p>
              <h6 class=" card-title">+45k</h6>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class=" row">
          <div class=" col-5">
            <!-- <div class=" numbers"> -->
              <p class=" card-category">Average</p>
              <h6 class=" card-title">+45k</h6>
            <!-- </div> -->
          </div>
          <div class=" col-7">
            <div class=" numbers">
              <p class=" card-category">Followers</p>
              <h6 class=" card-title">+45k</h6>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class=" card-footer">
        <hr />

        <div class=" stats">
          <i class=" icons icon-sound-wave"> </i> Last Research
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="col px-1">
    <div class=" card card-stats">
      <div class=" card-body">
        <div class=" row">
          <div class=" col-5">
            <div class=" info-icon text-center icon-primary">
              <i class=" icons icon-shape-star"> </i>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class=" col-7">
            <div class=" numbers">
              <p class=" card-category">Followers</p>
              <h6 class=" card-title">+45k</h6>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class=" row">
          <div class=" col-5">
            <!-- <div class=" numbers"> -->
              <p class=" card-category">Average</p>
              <h6 class=" card-title">+45k</h6>
            <!-- </div> -->
          </div>
          <div class=" col-7">
            <div class=" numbers">
              <p class=" card-category">Followers</p>
              <h6 class=" card-title">+45k</h6>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class=" card-footer">
        <hr />

        <div class=" stats">
          <i class=" icons icon-sound-wave"> </i> Last Research
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>


  <div class="col px-1">
    <div class=" card card-stats">
      <div class=" card-body">
        <div class=" row">
          <div class=" col-5">
            <div class=" info-icon text-center icon-primary">
              <i class=" icons icon-shape-star"> </i>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class=" col-7">
            <div class=" numbers">
              <p class=" card-category">Followers</p>
              <h6 class=" card-title">+45k</h6>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class=" row">
          <div class=" col-5">
            <!-- <div class=" numbers"> -->
              <p class=" card-category">Average</p>
              <h6 class=" card-title">+45k</h6>
            <!-- </div> -->
          </div>
          <div class=" col-7">
            <div class=" numbers">
              <p class=" card-category">Followers</p>
              <h6 class=" card-title">+45k</h6>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class=" card-footer">
        <hr />

        <div class=" stats">
          <i class=" icons icon-sound-wave"> </i> Last Research
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="col px-1">
    <div class=" card card-stats">
      <div class=" card-body">
        <div class=" row">
          <div class=" col-5">
            <div class=" info-icon text-center icon-primary">
              <i class=" icons icon-shape-star"> </i>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class=" col-7">
            <div class=" numbers">
              <p class=" card-category">Followers</p>
              <h6 class=" card-title">+45k</h6>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class=" row">
          <div class=" col-5">
            <!-- <div class=" numbers"> -->
              <p class=" card-category">Average</p>
              <h6 class=" card-title">+45k</h6>
            <!-- </div> -->
          </div>
          <div class=" col-7">
            <div class=" numbers">
              <p class=" card-category">Followers</p>
              <h6 class=" card-title">+45k</h6>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class=" card-footer">
        <hr />

        <div class=" stats">
          <i class=" icons icon-sound-wave"> </i> Last Research
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="col px-1">
    <div class=" card card-stats">
      <div class=" card-body">
        <div class=" row">
          <div class=" col-5">
            <div class=" info-icon text-center icon-primary">
              <i class=" icons icon-shape-star"> </i>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class=" col-7">
            <div class=" numbers">
              <p class=" card-category">Followers</p>
              <h6 class=" card-title">+45k</h6>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class=" row">
          <div class=" col-5">
            <!-- <div class=" numbers"> -->
              <p class=" card-category">Average</p>
              <h6 class=" card-title">+45k</h6>
            <!-- </div> -->
          </div>
          <div class=" col-7">
            <div class=" numbers">
              <p class=" card-category">Followers</p>
              <h6 class=" card-title">+45k</h6>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class=" card-footer">
        <hr />

        <div class=" stats">
          <i class=" icons icon-sound-wave"> </i> Last Research
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="col px-1">
    <div class=" card card-stats">
      <div class=" card-body">
        <div class=" row">
          <div class=" col-5">
            <div class=" info-icon text-center icon-primary">
              <i class=" icons icon-shape-star"> </i>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class=" col-7">
            <div class=" numbers">
              <p class=" card-category">Followers</p>
              <h6 class=" card-title">+45k</h6>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class=" row">
          <div class=" col-5">
            <!-- <div class=" numbers"> -->
              <p class=" card-category">Average</p>
              <h6 class=" card-title">+45k</h6>
            <!-- </div> -->
          </div>
          <div class=" col-7">
            <div class=" numbers">
              <p class=" card-category">Followers</p>
              <h6 class=" card-title">+45k</h6>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class=" card-footer">
        <hr />

        <div class=" stats">
          <i class=" icons icon-sound-wave"> </i> Last Research
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>


<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.slim.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: But here data for Average (above the footer) is not displayed in a row. This splits each character in a row (like A in a one line, v in next ...). But let me try this in my app and get back to you. Thanks

Comment: Thanks @Nisharg Shah. This works - I have reduced the font size for 3rd and 4th parameter, also changing 2nd row's  `col-5 & col-7` to be `col-6`. Updating my solution in my question.
But trying to change my icon on the top left corner, makes icon out of the info area. Can you please help with that? Thanks

Comment: please provide your code in HTML so I can solve your problem like above in my example you can see clear view but in your code I only see {{parameterComputeData.Max}} that type of text, and icons are not shows in your example, please also set icons so I clearly see it.

Comment: Hi @Nisharg Shah,  I have now  edited the updated code to remove the variable and also now icon displayed. Please help to 1. make the icon comparatively smaller 2. remove extra space above footer. Thanks in advance.

Comment: A gentle reminder - @Nisharg Shah, - to help me reduce the icon size relatively.

Comment: which extra space you want to remove in footer? which library you are using for icons?

Comment: Hi @nisharg Shah, I am using bootstrap icons. Just wanted to make that icon small, relative to the other parameter values (Average ...) displayed aside     For me, If I make the icons smaller, ==> the bgcolor and icon are not displayed together as its showing now.   AND  In my Question here above,  my last image shows the  extra space with the green arrow which is  just above the footer. Either I need to move the row slightly below to occupy this extra space or reduce this image. Waiting for your reply. Thanks